# Cassandra deletion best practice

Tags: cassandra-2.0

We have real time data coming in to our system. We have online queries which we need to serve. In order to serve these online queries we need are doing some pre-processing of the data so that we can serve faster.
Now my query is how do I preprocess the online real time data. There should be a way for me to figure out if the data was already processed or not. In order to find this difference, I have the following approaches:

- I can have a flag which says that data is processed or unprocessed, based on which i can further take a decision to process or not
- I can have a column family where I can insert the data **with a TTL**, and a topic in a message bus like kafka which gives me the row identifier in cassandra so that I can process this row in cassandra
- I can have a **column family** per day and a topic in a message bus like kafka which gives me the row identifier of the corresponding column family
- I can have a **keyspace** per day and  a topic in a message bus like kafka which gives me the row identifier of the corresponding column family

I read some where that if, the number of deletions increases, then the number of tombstones increases and result in slow query times. Now I am confused with the approach I have to chose among the above four or is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the datastax blog third option might be better fit.
[Cassandra Anti-patterns](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-anti-patterns-queues-and-queue-like-datasets)